# add auto increment(AUTO_INCREMENT) for already foreign key assigned attribute?

Tags: mysql

`user` table is defined without `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `user_id`. I want to change it to AUTO_INCREMENT field.
But trouble is user_id is referenced by many tables in foreign key constraint.

Can we solve it without deleting all foreign keys?

Comment: I understand that `user_id` is a `primary key`, right?

Comment: yes that's why it's used for foreign keys

Comment: do you have any solution without leaving all foreign key constraints?

Comment: You don't have to drop the fk, just remove relationship to the key, change it auto-increment and set back your relations again.

Comment: I would prefer you to use [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) wherein you don't have to execute all the queries to remove foreign key,adding an auto-inc, and then readding the foreign key. SQLyog provides GUI where you can add auto-increment with a click, as all the necessary SQL query would be executed by it.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it without deleting, using [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks):

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
--before alter, set AUTO_INCREMENT to a max existing value + 1 (see below)
alter table users modify column user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90dd1/1)

You can also do it with deleting, example below.

Assuming that `users_ref` is a reference table.

```
ALTER TABLE users_ref DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_users;
```

Set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` start to a max existing value + 1, ie:

```
select max(user_id) + 1 from users; --let's say it returns 5
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

Add `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
alter table users modify column user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Recreate constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE users_ref add CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id);
```

Demo can be found [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ebdf/1).